# Efficiently match elements of character vectors

Tags: r, match

I have a somewhat complicated situation of matching between elements of character vectors.
I have a query vector, e.g.:

```
query.vec <- c("a","b","c","d","k")
```

and a search vector, e.g.:

```
search.vec <- c("a","b,b1","c,d","e","f")
```

and I'd like to get the index of appearance of every element in the query vector within the search vector.
The elements in the query vector and in the search vector are unique, which means there's only one possible match per query vector element (or no match at all as in the case of `query.vec[5]`). However, more than one element in the query vector can match the same element in the search vector (e.g., `query.vec[3]` and `query.vec[4]` matching `search.vec[3]`).

The complexity arises since the search vector contains comma separated characters which still count as a match for my purposes (a match of an element in the query vector with one of the comma separated character elements in the search vector). This is why a simple `match` won't quite work.

I thought of:

```
unlist(sapply(query.vec, function(x) {
  idx <- which(grepl(x, search.vec) == TRUE)
  if(length(idx) == 0) idx <- NA
  return(idx)
}))
```

which gives the right answer:

```
 a  b  c  d  k 
 1  2  3  3 NA
```

but since in reality my query vector's length is ~8000 and the search vector's length is ~250,000 this solution is very slow. So I'm looking for something much faster.

Comment: Have you tried `strsplit`?

Comment: No because I think it's even slower than my solution.

Comment: Since performance is important to you, it would probably be good to clarify some edge cases: what to do if an element of `query.vec` occurs more than once in `search.vec`, or can one assume that will never happen?

Comment: `x <- strsplit(search.vec, "");tbl <- table(x); tbl[match(names(tbl), query.vec)] `. Or something like that

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be sufficient:

```
query.vec <- c("a","b","c","d","k")
search.vec <- c("a","b,b1","c,d","e","f")

split.search.vec.list = strsplit(search.vec, ",")
split.search.vec = unlist(split.search.vec.list)
names(split.search.vec) = unlist(sapply(1:length(split.search.vec.list), function(x) rep(x, length(split.search.vec.list[[x]]))))
idx = match(query.vec, split.search.vec)
idx[which(!is.na(idx))] = names(split.search.vec)[idx[which(!is.na(idx))]]
idx = as.integer(idx)
```